# List of Dictionaries which contain lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

With the data structure

```
dict_list [0] {key1: [1, 2, 3]
               key2: [4, 5, 6]
               key3: [7, 8, 9] 
               key4: [10, 11, 12]      }
          ...
          ...

          [4] {key13: [37, .., 39]
               key14: [40, .., ..]
               key15: [43, .., ..]
               key16: [46, .., 48] }
```

I want to segment each portion in a short list column by column, dictionary by dictionary.

So for example:

```
a = [1, 4, 7, 10]
b = [2, 5, 8, 11]
....
z = [39, .., .., 40]
```

These lists (or tuples) are created and will be sent to a numpy function as *args and the function will be iterated for each list a,b,c,d.....z.

So far my code is:

```
 for i in range(len(read_list)): #iterating dictionary list to extract values
   for key, value in read_list[i].iteritems():
        print value[0]
```

This prints 1,4,7,10,12....37.....46 all in one list and only for 1 column.  But my problem is I need to easily iterate out blocks of 4 and for each column as described above.  Since I will be passing each list (a-z) to a function as the arguments is there a more efficient data structure I could use than my own idea?

Comment: since it is stored in normal dictionary format the  data will not be in order is that ok

Comment: @VigneshKalai If you mean say: "a = [7, 10, 4, 1]" or a = [4, 7 ,1 ,10] instead then yes this is ok as the function doesn't require any order in the list.  Any other loss of structure could be problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and pass the `dict_list` values [unpacked](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).
Something like this -

```
>>> [sorted(c) for e in dict_list for c in zip(*e.values())]
[[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12], [37, 40, 43, 46], [39, 41, 44, 47], [40, 42, 45, 48]]
```

**EDIT**
This is the `dict_list` is used to test this(constructing this from the description in the question) -

```
dict_list = [
    {   
        "key1": [1, 2, 3],
        "key2": [4, 5, 6],
        "key3": [7, 8, 9],
        "key4": [10, 11, 12]
    },
    {   
        "key13": [37, 39, 40],
        "key14": [40,41,42] ,
        "key15": [43,44, 45] ,
        "key16": [46,47,48]
    }
]
```

Comment: @cc6g11 I tried it on Python 2.7.3. What version do you have?

Comment: @Kamehameha 2.7.10...I just wrote out the nested loops explicitly and it worked.... sorted(c) outputs all values of the file row by row though

Comment: @cc6g11 Hmmm. It shouldn't be a problem. [Try running it here](https://repl.it/xTF)

Comment: @Kamehameha got it working there and in my project.  However, I get outputs as 1,2,3,4,5,6..........48 all in one list :S

Comment: @Kamehameha that structure you use is a list of dictionaries yes?  would the fact I'm on 2.7.10 be causing problems with the list or zip functions?

Comment: @cc6g11 I don't think so(It would work on all python 2.7). Is it possible for you print your `dict_list` and add it to your question? Is it similar to the one that I've used in my new edit?

Comment: @Kamehameha turns out it was an error in how I was reading in the file which was giving me 1 dictionary instead of a list of them, not your code!!!